# Поиск с помощью стеммера

Tags: php, html, mysql

Подскажите статью, где подробно написано, как сделать поиск по mysql с помощью стеммера.
Сколько ни читал, ничего не получается. (( Выдаются ошибки...

Answer (score 1):

Вот, например: ["Как организовать поиск на сайте, использующем PHP и MySQL?"](http://marvic.ru/zapiski/php/poisk-na-saite-php-i-mysql).

```
// подключили
require_once('stemmer.php');

$stemmer = new Lingua_Stem_Ru();
...
// определили корень
$value = $stemmer->stem_word($value);
...
```

где `Lingua_Stem_Ru` - это определение корня слова методом стеммера Портера.

И в дополнение: [полнотекстовый поиск в MySQL](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Fulltext_Search.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Boolean Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html).